# Standard account in Windows 8 takes too much time to reach metro screen

Tags: windows-8, performance, login

I have a Windows 8 system in which there is an admin and a standard account. The admin account will take only 10-20 seconds to reach the metro screen during startup. While the standard account takes nearly 2 minutes to reach its metro screen. Why is it so? How can I remove this delay?

Comment: When you say  "Guest account", do you mean a standard non-administrator account?  Or an actual temporary guest account?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Guest account is non-administrator account. It is a permanent account.

Comment: I would recommend you clarify that then as Windows 8 has support for actual [guest accounts](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/what-is-a-guest-account) and it may confuse people trying to help you.  Your [tag:guest] tag is also not appropriate given this.

Comment: capture a boot trace of the slowness: http://pastebin.com/CYGqRZXE

Comment: (1) Is this standard account a local or Microsoft account? (2) Does enabling or disabling Accelerated Graphics in Internet Explorer have an effect? (3) Is the Windows Firewall service disabled? (4) Check the log at `C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Local\Temp\WinStore.log` and the Event Log for clues.

Comment: @harrymc (1) It is a guest account. (2) I don't tried it till. (3) Firewall is enabled. (4) What to check at the log files ?

Comment: (2) Let us know the result. (4) Any error message.

Comment: @harrymc (2) I disabled it and I think it reduced some time. But still it is taking 20-25 seconds. (4) No error message.

Comment: Is it also slow when you [boot to desktop mode](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2043243/how-to-boot-to-desktop-mode-in-windows-8-1.html)? If not, what happens if you immediately click on the Start button (or press the Windows key)?

Comment: @harrymc My OS is Windows 8 and so I can only boot to the metro screen.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was 8.1. You could still use a product such as [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/).

Answer (score -1):

Go into Task Manager and then go to the Startup section. Disable any apps that you don't use or those that have a high startup load on the machine. Be careful not to remove any services or drivers you need like Touchpad or Audio Manager Service. You should also consider running a virus scan on your profile just to be sure that there are no viruses.